# graph api get all friends using loop

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

with previous fql it was so easy to get all freidns, but with the version 2. graph api, it has something like this

> `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=&offset=&limit`

which act as pagination to limit each request of number of friends. I've about 500 friends, but in the first result I saw only 8. How can I loop through the offset param since every user has different number of friends? or I shouldn't use loop at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop all the requests while you still have friends to be listed in next page.

```
/friends?format=json&offset=0&limit=10
```

You will be increasing your offset each time with the value of your limit, to advance in pagination.

Comment: is this the correct way of using friends? I saw something like taggable_friends.. how is this loop method different than tht?